# How do I get Child of a Child Page Timber/Twig WordPress

Tags: wordpress, timber

How do I get the Child of a Child Page to display on a .twig template?

```
Parent Page
— First Sibling
— — Second Sibling
— — — Third Sibling
```

I am getting the children of the First Sibling with

```
{% for child in post.children %}
  <li class="pb-3"><a href="{{ child.link }}">{{ child.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

How do I go one further deeper? Timber/Twig WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this a Child post is a post and because of that it has children if given

```
{% for child in post.children %}
  <li class="pb-3"><a href="{{ child.link }}">{{ child.title }}</a></li>
  {% if child.children|length > 0 %}
    {% for child in child.children %}
      <li class="pb-3"><a href="{{ child.link }}">{{ child.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Timber/Twig, and you're using ACF, you can choose a Post Object of Page, select the title of the page that you are wanting to add as the Post Object, and to grab the child pages you can do something like this:

```
{% for child in Post(list.page).children %}

  <li class="pb-3"><a href="{{ child.link }}" target="{{ child.link.target }}">{{ child.title }}</a></li>

{% endfor %}
```